# How to put them all in the middle? How to make HTML automatically recognize whether the answer is right or wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move all four boxes and buttons to the middle to be centered.

I try to enter the correct answer, but when I submit, it shows that the verification fails, so I want to know how to let HTML automatically identify whether the answer is correct or wrong, and give different outputs.

This is the HTML code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Verification Code</title>
     <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script>
      // Generate a random linear equation in one variable
      function generateEquation() {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var operator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var equation = "";

        switch (operator) {
          case 0:
            equation = a + "x + " + b + " = " + (a*x+b);
            break;
          case 1:
            equation = a + "x - " + b + " = " + (a*x-b);
            break;
        }

        return equation;
      }

      // Check if the user's input is correct
      function checkAnswer() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
        var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value;
        var userInput = input1 + input2 + input3 + input4;
        var answer = equations[0] + equations[1] + equations[2] + equations[3];

        if (userInput === answer.toString()) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Verification succeeded!";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Verification failed. Please try again.";
        }
      }

      // Generate a new equation and display it on the screen
      function newEquation() {
        var equation = generateEquation();
        var answer = eval(equation.split('=')[1]);
        equations = answer.toString().split("");
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = equation;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
        document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input3").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input4").value = "";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Verification Code</h1>
    <p>Please solve the following equation:</p>
    <p id="equation"></p>
    <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="X" size="2">
    <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="X" size="2">
    <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="X" size="2">
    <input type="text" id="input4" placeholder="X" size="2">
    <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button>
    <button onclick="newEquation()">New Equation</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>newEquation()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
}

button{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.

Style fix using a div with a style to force middle centered.
Im not sure about the 4 boxes, because your random generation only allow answers with range 1-10 then i only used 1one box. I made some variables global to allow easy check. I put style in the same html but you can easily move all that style stuff in your css file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Verification Code</title>
     <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script>

        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var operator = 0;
        var answer = 0;

      // Generate a random linear equation in one variable
      function generateEquation() {
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        operator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var equation = "";

        console.log("a: ", a);
        console.log("b: ", b);
        console.log("operator: ", operator);

        switch (operator) {
          case 0:
            equation = a + "x + " + b + " = " + (a*x+b);
            break;
          case 1:
            equation = a + "x - " + b + " = " + (a*x-b);
            break;
        }


        return equation;
      }

      // Check if the user's input is correct
      function checkAnswer() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
/*         var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
        var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value; */
        var userInput = input1;
        switch (operator) {
          case 0:
          answer = ((a*x+b) - b )/a;
            break;
          case 1:
          answer = ((a*x-b) + b )/a;
            break;
        }


        console.log("userInput: ", userInput)
        console.log("ANSWER: ", answer)

        if (userInput == answer) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Verification succeeded!";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Verification failed. Please try again.";
        }
      }

      // Generate a new equation and display it on the screen
      function newEquation() {
        var equation = generateEquation();
        var answer = eval(equation.split('=')[1]);
        equations = answer.toString().split("");
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = equation;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
        document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
/*         document.getElementById("input2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input3").value = "";
        document.getElementById("input4").value = ""; */
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
      }
    </script>

    <style>
        h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
}

button{
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Verification Code</h1>
    <p>Please solve the following equation:</p>
    <p id="equation"></p>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="X" size="5">
<!--         <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="X" size="2">
        <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="X" size="2">
        <input type="text" id="input4" placeholder="X" size="2"> -->
        <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button>
        <button onclick="newEquation()">New Equation</button>
    </div>

    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>newEquation()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a refreshed equation and changed the language you used in your javascript.

```js
if (userInput == answer) {
    newEquation();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Correct, just one more equation.";
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""}, 4000)
}
```

In the same way as Claudio I centred your elements with CSS.

Below is an example
https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/QWVvgzz?editors=1010

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var x = 0;
var operator = 0;
var answer = 0;

// Generate a random linear equation in one variable
function generateEquation() {
  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  operator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  var equation = "";

  console.log("a: ", a);
  console.log("b: ", b);
  console.log("operator: ", operator);

  switch (operator) {
    case 0:
      equation = a + "x + " + b + " = " + (a * x + b);
      break;
    case 1:
      equation = a + "x - " + b + " = " + (a * x - b);
      break;
  }

  return equation;
}

// Check if the user's input is correct
function checkAnswer() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var userInput = input1;
  switch (operator) {
    case 0:
      answer = (a * x + b - b) / a;
      break;
    case 1:
      answer = (a * x - b + b) / a;
      break;
  }

  console.log("userInput: ", userInput);
  console.log("ANSWER: ", answer);

  if (userInput == answer) {
    newEquation();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Correct, just one more equation.";
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""}, 4000)
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Verification failed. Please try again.";
  }
}

// Generate a new equation and display it on the screen
function newEquation() {
  var equation = generateEquation();
  equations = answer.toString().split("");
  document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = equation;
  document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
}
newEquation();
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Verification Code</h1>
<p>Please solve the following equation:</p>
<p id="equation"></p>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="X" size="5">
  <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button>
  <button onclick="newEquation()">New Equation</button>
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```